# Connect javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I'm beginning to learn JavaScript , and browser API. Why, if I press the "save" button , the pop up window does not appears in the browser ? Where am I wrong?

```
<label for="txtNome"><input id="txtNome" type="text" value=""/><br/></label>
<label for="txtCognome"><input id="txtCognome" type="text" value=""/><br/></label>
<button id="btnSalva"/>Salva</button><br/>

<script>
    var model = { nome: "Mario", cognome: "Rossi" };

    var view = {
        txtNome: document.getElementById("txtNome"),
        txtCognome: document.getElementById("txtCognome"),
        btnSalva: document.getElementById("btnSalva")
    };

    var controller;
        controller = {

        init: function () {
            view.txtNome.value = model.nome;
            view.txtCognome.value = model.cognome;
            view.btnSalva.onclick = controller.salva;
        },

        salva: function () {
            model.nome = view.txtNome.value;
            model.cognome = view.txtCognome.value;
            window.alert("FATTO");
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to world of ECMAScript aka JavaScript ! Because you forgot to add an **event listener** to the button. A function that will execute when button _clicks_.

Comment: are you using some kind of MVC framework?  There's nothing there that "runs" - just a bunch of variables.

Comment: change `view.btnSalva.onclick = controller.salva` into `view.btnSalva.onclick = this.salva`

use **this** and do not forget to call the init method as well.. onclick or so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `controller.init()`, otherwise your code does nothing, you were just declaring some objects.

```js
var model = { nome: "Mario", cognome: "Rossi" };

var view = {
  txtNome: document.getElementById("txtNome"),
  txtCognome: document.getElementById("txtCognome"),
  btnSalva: document.getElementById("btnSalva")
};

var controller;
controller = {

  init: function () {
    view.txtNome.value = model.nome;
    view.txtCognome.value = model.cognome;
    view.btnSalva.onclick = controller.salva;
  },

  salva: function () {
    model.nome = view.txtNome.value;
    model.cognome = view.txtCognome.value;
    window.alert("FATTO");
  }
};

controller.init(); //call init!
```

```html
<label for="txtNome"><input id="txtNome" type="text" value=""/><br/></label>
<label for="txtCognome"><input id="txtCognome" type="text" value=""/><br/></label>
<button id="btnSalva"/>Salva</button><br/>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was so obvious that I'm ashamed of having asked for it!!

Comment: No problem, sometimes it happens!